# A model which has only one undefinable element over a language with only a finite number of symbols

Tags: logic, model-theory

I try to solve the problem 1.3.14 in Chang and Keisler's Model theory:

> For each $n\in\omega$, find a model $\mathfrak{A}_n$ for $\mathcal{L}$ a language with only a finite number of symbols, which has exactly $n$ undefinable elements.

It is easy to solve when $n\neq 1$ (just take the language which only has a equality symbol and $n$-element set as a domain.) However, as this textbook remarked, the case of $n=1$ is extremely hard for me. All of my attempts are failed and I don't know how to solve the problem.

So my question is: there is a model which has *only one* undefinable element over a language with *only a finite number of symbols*? Thanks for any help.

---

This question is not duplicate with [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5713/53976) because this question only consider the model for language with *finitely many* symbols. In this question, I regard the equality symbol as logical symbols.

Comment: I heard that this was a "bonus" question in the model theory course earlier this year (someone asked me if I have any idea, they said that the teacher said there was a very difficult example, and whoever writes it nicely will get extra credit or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently very difficult. There is an article by Harvey Friedman that gives an example

https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/UniqueUndElt010913-2b6widm.pdf

In general, the double-starred problems in CK are closer to research problems than exercises...

Comment: In third edition of CK, this problem is only one-starred problem. Anyway, I misunderstand the difficulty of this problem before you explain.